# AJAX is returnin NaN on codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter-3

So I have a function on a controller on this path usercontroller(controller name/ajaxp(controller function). That look like this, nothing fancy:

```
public function ajaxp(){
echo "received";
}
```

Here is the path where I want my AJAX call to get.

I have a select box that look like this :

```
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Apartament</label>
<select onchange="showUser(this.value)" name ="txtApartament1" class="form-control">
    <?php foreach($getEntry as $value) { ?>
    <option><?php echo $value->apartament ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

onchange will trigger this AJAX :

```js
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    var url = <?php base_url();?>+"usercontroller/ajaxp?q="+str;
    console.log(url);
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtApartament1").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtApartament1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url ,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

But my url will be :

```
(index):258 GET http://localhost/adminigniter1/NaN65 404 (Not Found)
```

insted of:

```
http://localhost/adminigniter1/usercontroller/ajaxp
```

And the console.log output will be:

> NaN65

65 is the actual **str** from my select box that I want to sent to the cotroller. And the NaN part I think comes from this part :

```js
var url = <?php base_url();?>+"usercontroller/ajaxp?q="+str;
```

Where I try to append the controller function path, that string is seen by javascript by NaN and doesn't return the corect URL. There is a way to fix it? (I'm quite new with javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<option>` has no value.

Try with this : 
`<option value="<?php echo $value->apartament ?>"><?php echo $value->apartament ?></option>`

And your url definition have to be like this :

`var url = "<?php base_url();?>usercontroller/ajaxp?q="+str;`

Comment: This looks goot, right now I will get : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null on the document.getElementById("txtApartament1").innerHTML = this.responseText; , what can that mean ?

Comment: this means that `document.getElementById("txtApartament1")` doesn't exist. Put an id to your select : `<select onchange="showUser(this.value)" name ="txtApartament1" id="txtApartament1" class="form-control">`

Comment: But there is name ="txtApartament1" on my select box, do I have to make it with id = "txtApartament1" ?

Comment: Yes, or you can change your selector by `document.getElementsByName('txtApartament1')[0]`

Comment: note that when `value` is left off `<option>` it will automatically be the text when selected so if text and value are same value not required

Answer (score 1):

you are missing javascript string quotes quotes around `<?php base_url();?>`

try

```
var url = "<?php base_url();?>" + "usercontroller/ajaxp?q="+str;
```